# Why couldn't my program find `args[0]` file in command-line mode?

Tags: java

My code is as follows:

```
package chapter14_io;
import java.io.*;
public class BufferedStreamDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            byte[] data = new byte[1]; 

            File srcFile = new File(args[0]); 
            File desFile = new File(args[1]); 

            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = 
                new BufferedInputStream(
                         new FileInputStream(srcFile)); 
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = 
                new BufferedOutputStream(
                         new FileOutputStream(desFile));

            System.out.println("複製檔案：" + 
                             srcFile.length() + "位元組");

            while(bufferedInputStream.read(data) != -1) { 
                bufferedOutputStream.write(data); 
            }

            // 將緩衝區中的資料全部寫出 
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();

            // 關閉串流 
            bufferedInputStream.close(); 
            bufferedOutputStream.close(); 

            System.out.println("複製完成"); 
        } 
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { 
            System.out.println(
                    "using: java UseFileStream src des"); 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        catch(IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    }

}
```

cmd command use following words.↓

> C:\Users\user>java chapter14_io.BufferedStreamDemo FileDemo.java
>   FileDemo.txt java.io.FileNotFoundException: FileDemo.java
>   (系統找不到指定的檔案。)
>           at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:220)
>           at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:158)
>           at chapter14_io.BufferedStreamDemo.main(BufferedStreamDemo.java:14)

Comment: Maybe it 's not running in the expected directory. You can check by adding this line: `System.out.println("Current dir:" + new File(".").getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: A good practice would be to use absolute paths as argument.

Comment: Or just execute `dir`, and see if you have a FileDemo.java file listed.

Comment: I'd suggest that you both check that `args` is at least two items long and iterate through `args`, outputting the received values, to confirm that you're getting the input you expect.

Comment: I have used following cmd to solve problem. Thank you all.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\user>java chapter14_io.BufferedStreamDemo "C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\Project test initial\src\chapter14_io\FileDemo.java" "C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\Project test initial\src\chapter14_io\FileDemo.txt"

Answer (score 0):

### **I have used following cmd to solve problem. Thank you all.**

---

> C:\Users\user>java chapter14_io.BufferedStreamDemo
>   "C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\Project test
>   initial\src\chapter14_io\FileDemo.java"
>   "C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\Project test
>   initial\src\chapter14_io\FileDemo.txt" 
>   複製檔案：1706位元組 
>   複製完成